# Xpath select query with also relative top level node in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am using xpath to query my xml file in C#.

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

And my C# code is

```
XPathNavigator nav;
XPathDocument docNav;
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
String strExpression;

docNav = new XPathDocument(@"C:\\DCU\\XQUE.xml");

nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
// This expression uses standard XPath syntax.

strExpression = "/bookstore[./book/price>35.00]";

NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);

while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", NodeIter.Current.OuterXml);
}
```

But I want to get output like this,

```
<bookstore>
<book>
  <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

I think anything missing with my xpath query line, please lead me a way out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're misunderstanding the purpose of XPath selection and what it can do.  XPath won't create a whole new XML document for you.  The typical choice for taking an XML input and producing a different XML output is to use XSLT.  This would do it in your case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book[price &lt;= 35]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you really want to use just C# to do this, you could always do the following:

```
XPathNavigator nav;
XPathDocument docNav;
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
String strExpression;

docNav = new XPathDocument(@"C:\\DCU\\XQUE.xml");

nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
// This expression uses standard XPath syntax.

strExpression = "/bookstore/book[price > 35.00]";

NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);

Console.WriteLine("<bookstore>");
while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", NodeIter.Current.OuterXml);
}
Console.WriteLine("</bookstore>");
```

Answer (score 1):

That expression selects `<bookstore>` elements, so the output will be the whole `<bookstore>` (with all its child `book` elements).  If you want specific books you need to use a different XPath

```
strExpression = "/bookstore/book[price>35.00]";
```

which will print just the `<book>` elements that match, but without the surrounding `<bookstore>` tags.

Comment: But I want to do this by query including `<bookstore>` tag

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee in which case you're no longer simply selecting elements out of your original XML, you're constructing a _new_ XML document based on the old one.  Have you considered using XSLT for this purpose.